# Does ng-repeat support recursion on itself?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Suppose I have a json like this: 

    `{
      "data": {
        "data": {
          "data": {
            "set": "1"
          }
        }
      }
    }`

I want to use ng-repeat to loop through this json, however I want to loop through it dynamically, I will not know how many data objects I will have, sometimes it could be 3, and sometimes it could be 5,6,7, etc.

How can I loop through this with ng-repeat without having to write ng-repeat as many times as there are data objects.

In javascript I would just write something like this:

    `function loop(data) {
      if (data.data) {
        loop(data.data)
      }
    }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the same function you would use and call it from the ng-repeat

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="v in array">
      {{getValue(v)}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and the function in the controller like so:

```
$scope.getValue = function(item){
  if(item.data){
    return $scope.getValue(item.data);
  }else{
    return item.set;
  }
};
```

Here is a link to a working example http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/dXOOVo

Comment: Thanks @Michael, that works great!

Another question though, what if I had this json structure:

 `
       {
         "data": {
            "data": {
              "data": {
                 "set": "1"
               },
              "set": 4
             },
           "set": 3
         },
        "set": "2"
        }
`

How can I process all the sets from the example above?

Comment: Here is an example with the updated json structure, modifying markup to included a nested ng-repeat and changes to getValue function. http://www.codepen.io/mkl/pen/ZOBxNW